# Download huge data using StreamingOutput available in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have requirement where I am having some huge volume[Approx 20000+ records] of employee details and respective contact details to be downloaded in one spreadsheet. Current system is not capable to handle this much data and responding with internal server error. Since my application is build with Java + JAX RS so I am working with StreamingOutput and binding the data to one spreadsheet. What is the best to handle such kind of request? How can I break it into chunks and finally concatenate and create one single file.

Comment: Is spreadsheet filetype is part of the requirement? Can it be csv?

Comment: What is the stacktrace of "internal server error" if it's in java?

Comment: Are you building the spreadsheet in memory ?? Are you loading the 20000+ records in memory to start building the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, Spreadsheet is a part of the requirement.. Internal server error is happening because of some time out is defined and also the point I am hitting the method the system becomes unresponsive completely.

Comment: Yes, Loading the data in memory from Database and then writing it to the spreadhseet using StreamingOutput.